# VBA Assign variable value to cells

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to use VBA in Excel to auto-generate a worksheet based on some inputs.

My problem is that when I try to assign a variable to a cell with VBA, nothing happens.

This test code worked:

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
```

This code (the code I care about) doesn't:

```
Const ROW_START As Integer = 3

For row = ROW_START To (ROW_START + 10000) Step 1
    Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(row, RAM_COL).Value = Rnd()
Next
```

This also worked, although it only used Rnd() once (which I should have expected):

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A1:A10000") = Rnd()
```

I have numerous such loops, none of which work.  I also try to assign strings to cell values in a while, which also does not work.

The worksheet referenced by sheetName is created without any problems.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: What line in your code produces an error?

Comment: I checked the loop and was adding to cells fine for me, I would guess there is an issue with `sheetName` or `RAM_COL` not being defined. As alex mentioned, would recommend to step through the code (using F8) to narrow down where the issue is then come back

Comment: My issue was a typo in one of the variable names (all of the variables above were initialized, just one wasn't the correct name).  I had also stepped through the code and it never broke, it just didn't do anything.  There was also no indication on the excel VB IDE that the var wasn't declared.  (RAM_COL was supposed to be RAND_COL btw).

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the undeclared or unassigned variables, bulk loading a formula and reverting to the result values will significantly speed up the operation.

```
Dim rw As Long, row_start As Long, row_end As Long, ram_col As Long, sheet_name As String
row_start = 3
row_end = row_start + 10000
ram_col = 1
sheet_name = "Sheet2"

With Worksheets(sheet_name)
    'this should take less than ½ second
    With .Range(.Cells(row_start, ram_col), .Cells(row_end, ram_col))
        .Clear
        .Formula = "=rand()"
        .Value = .Value2
    End With

    'this takes 3-4 seconds
    For rw = row_start To row_end Step 1
        .Cells(rw, ram_col).Value = Rnd()
    Next

End With
```

Comment: Why does Cells(row, col).Value = anything crash VBA without any error message?